# try to use xfire client to retrieve data from DSS sample

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am going through the RDBMS sample of data service server now. the service is in 'localhost:9763/services/RDBMSSample?wsdl` and works fine. so I want to use a Xfire client to test the service and for further use. here is my code:

```
    import java.net.URL;
import org.codehaus.xfire.client.Client;


public class CaClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
        String s = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
        Client client = new Client(new URL("http://***:9763/services/RDBMSSample?wsdl"));
        Object[] results = client.invoke("productsInfo", new Object[]{null});
        System.out.println(results[0]);
        }
        finally {

        }
    }

}
```

Then, I run this sample code in eclipse but get the following error:

```
06, 2013 4:16:33  org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.HttpChannel sendViaClient
SEVERE: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I disable the SSL?

Comment: Check your service endpoint.//localhost:9763/services/RDBMSSample?wsdl` // is the wsdl link. SErvice url would be, //http://localhost:9763/services/RDBMSSample//

Comment: but I try what you say and failed. I think in fact the xfire client need a wsdl url instead of a service Endpoint

Comment: Try with simple axis client..and see

Comment: then I see the samples in DSS helps a lot. thanks